# I sometimes read about Marauders splash damage... They do have an AOE affect?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am a little bit confused, because i always thought marauder had only a single target hit, but when i hear about splash damage, i get confused. Do they have an aoe? is that trigger but the slowing shot upgrade?

Comment: do you have a link to a place where you've read about marauders having splash damage?  that could help us explain the confusion.

Answer (score 11):

Marauders only inflict damage on a single target, the one they are shooting at. They do not have any splash damage.

However, regarding their concussive shells, it's a bit different:

- In the single-player campaign, the "jackhammer concussive shells" upgrade makes marauders slow not only the target they are shooting at but also targets in a small radius around it - so their slowing effect is splashed, but not the damage.
- In multiplayer melee mode, marauders only slow their target, so the slow effect isn't splashed.

Comment: starcraft.wikia.com shows the splashing [Jackhammer Concussive Shells](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Marauder#Wings_of_Liberty) that are used in the campaign, and sc2armory.com shows the single-target [Concussive Shells](http://sc2armory.com/game/terran/units/marauder#abilities) upgrade used in multiplayer.